# Linq to get names of child's child

Tags: linq

I want to write a list of a dishwasher-names to a CSV.

A user has a list of houses, and a house has a list of dishwashers

The CSV part is done, but im not very experienced with LINQ.

How do i get the names for the dishwashers? I cant add ".name" to the LINQ below.

```
string Join(",",User.Houses.SelectMany(h => h.Dishwashers))
```

Comment: what does `Houses` hold ? `House` ? then what is class structure of `House` and `Dishwashers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to project the dishwasher name.

`string.Join(string separator, params string[] value)` expects an array of names in your case.

```
string Join(",", User.Houses.SelectMany(h => h.Dishwashers).Select(dw => dw.Name).ToArray())
```

I expect something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;


class House
{
    public Dishwasher[] Dishwashers{get;set;}
}

class Dishwasher 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var houses = new [] {
            new House(){ Dishwashers = new [] { new Dishwasher(){ Name="DW1"}, new Dishwasher(){ Name="DW12"} }},
            new House(){ Dishwashers = new [] { new Dishwasher(){ Name="DW2"}, new Dishwasher(){ Name="DW22"} }}
        };

        var allDishwashers = houses.SelectMany(h=> h.Dishwashers);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", allDishwashers.Select(dw=> dw.Name).ToArray())); 
    }
}
```

Here you have a working .NETFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fat1fM

Comment: Instead of ToArray i used ToList(). But otherwise you are correct! Thanks! :)

Comment: That works too. I added a .NETFiddle that simulates your situation.